# Can We use Array Element in DomDocument and nesting xpath?

Tags: php, arrays, xpath, nested, domdocument

I am using the following code

```
    $page_data=array();//$title_links is array having urls
     $nodearr=array();
    foreach ($title_links as $b_url)
    {
        $page_data[]= mycurl($b_url);//my curl function, it is okay

        $dom2 = new DOMDocument();//creating new domdocument object inside a domdocument object
        @$dom2->loadHTML($page_data[]); 
        $xpath_cat = new DOMXPath($dom2);//same as domdocument , nesting xpath
        $nodelist = $xpath_cat->query('//span[@class="zg_hrsr_ladder"]', $dom2);
//echo nodeslist;

foreach ($nodelist as $node) {
   $nodearr[] = $node->textContent;
 }


    }
```

so the scenerio is ,

> I am nesting a 'domdocument' inside an other 'DomDocument'
>
> using 'foreach loop', i am inserting Array Element in DomDocument
>
> aslo, as i am nestind domdocument inside domdocument , so i am
>   declaring new xpath query

The Question is ...

Doing so is okay? Is it a acceptable Programming technique?

Pros and Cons?

Any ALternative to it?

> Clarification:
>
> $title_links is obtained using curl, it is urls
>   extracted from web page using domdocument and xpath query.
>
> so
>   $title_links is at first level of xpath and domdocument, and $nodelist
>   is at the 2nd level of nesting od xpath and dom-document

Comment: What exactly is the end goal? And how are you nesting DOMDocuments exactly - are you extending that class and this is code one of the methods of your extension?

Comment: No, I am not using OOP or classes in the code, its simple php code, and the final thing, what i have is, i want to run xpath query on the pages brought by "mycurl()", failing in running the query. So i decided to make the concept clear before proceding further

Comment: unfortunately, neither concept nor scenario is clear to me. Why are you using cURL to fetch the URLs, instead of http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php? And what do you mean by nesting XPath? The code above is not helping to illustrate your goals. If you want to query multiple documents, do it one document at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's failing is this: `@$dom2->loadHTML($page_data[]);`

`[]` can only be used for assignment, not reading. You need to actually have a key you can reference. I would probably do it like this:

```
$page_data=array();//$title_links is array having urls
foreach ($title_links as $key => $b_url)
{
    $page_data[$key]= mycurl($b_url);//my curl function, it is okay

    $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
    $dom2->loadHTML($page_data[$key]); // error suppression is evil!
    $xpath_cat = new DOMXPath($dom2);

}
```

What's still unclear to me is how exactly there is any nesting going on here; you're not nesting anything, you are just iterating over an array.